# Can the Squeeze Theorem be Applied to a Restricted Domain?

Tags: calculus

I am in highschool Ap Calculus and we just learned about the Squeeze Theorem:

> If $f(x)≤g(x)≤h(x)$ for all numbers, and at some point $x=k$ we have
> $f(k)=h(k)$, then $g(k)$ must also be equal to them.

It states that the inequality must be true for all real numbers but I was wondering:

If $f(x)\le g(x) \le h(x)$ is true within the domain $[c, d]$, and $K$ is within $[c, d]$ and $f(k)=h(k)=t$, does $g(k)=t$?

Comment: You forgot the limits. The squeeze theorem says that if$f(x)\leq g(x) \leq h(x)$ and $$\lim_{x \to k} f(x)=\lim_{x \to k} h(x)=L$$, then $$\lim_{x \to k} g(x) = L$$

Comment: This baby squeeze theorem is quite cute lol.

Comment: @SenZen My apologies; I should have been more specific about the interval ($f(x)$, $g(x)$, $h(x)$ defined on some interval $I$, except possibly at $k$).

Comment: I meant the squeeze theorem without limits, just the function values, I.e. baby squeeze theorem. It's probably not what you meant to write but it's probably the most uselessly trivial thing I've ever seen and made me laugh lol.

Comment: I am aware that I forgot the limits but that statement is what I found on google and I wanted a direct quotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, the Squeeze Theorem is applicable whenever $f, g$, and $h$ are functions defined on some interval $J$, except possibly at one of its limit points, say, $x_0 \in J$. It proceeds to say that if $f(x) \leq g(x) \leq h(x)$ for every $x \in J \setminus \{x_0\}$, and

$$ \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to x_0} h(x) = L \in \mathbb{R},$$

then $\lim_{x \to x_0} g(x)$ exists and coincides with $L$. In particular, if $J = [c, d]$ and both $f$ and $h$ converge to $t \in \mathbb{R}$ as $x$ approaches some limit point $x_0$ of $[c, d]$, then $g$ will also converge to $t$ as $x$ approaches $x_0$.